# Pandas data cleaning for selected column only

Tags: python, pandas

I am recently working with Pandas and I am facing issue while data cleaning process Here I need to replace column value having dot pattern i.e "..." or "............" in Pandas to NaN

[My actual dataframe i.e. energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvey5.png)

What I am doing now is simply using replace method to replace this dotted pattern to NaN

Here's my code:

```
energy.replace('...*','NaN', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

My output:

[My output after the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIG6v.png)

I have successfully cleaned my data having **dotted pattern to NaN** but my **country column all value also got changed to NaN** as seen in 2nd image. I tried searching this issue on how to change only selected column values and got various method but none work for my scenarios.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I have cleaned my data correctly without changing country name by applying replace method to individual column                                                                                                                                             
**energy['Column_Name'].replace('\.*','NaN', regex=True, inplace=True)**              But this is not a suitable method as if I would have got 90 columns with this **" ... "** pattern in column and I want that value to get replaced with NaN applying replace method column wise would be really bad !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your country column changed because you are using a regex and in regex `.` is a symbol for *anything*. You might want to use a regex like this `'\.+'` which will match any number of `.` characters. This is a solution that does not require you to restrict execution to a certain column.

The output when using `\.+` in `energy.replace(r'\.+', 'NaN', regex=True, inplace=True)` on my mocked model of your data is:

```
>>> energy
       Country Energy Supply Energy Supply Per Capita  % Renewable
0  some_string      16846846                      484     85.48648
1  some_string      16846846                      484     85.48648
2  some_string      16846846                      484     85.48648
3  some_string           NaN                      NaN     85.48648
4  some_string      16846846                      484     85.48648
```

For completeness sake, you can also restrict the execution to just a certain column, by calling the replace function only on that column:

```
energy['Energy Supply'].replace(r'\.+', 'NaN', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This gives the output of:

```
>>> energy
       Country Energy Supply Energy Supply Per Capita % Renewable
0  some_string      16846846                      484     85.4865
1  some_string      16846846                      484     85.4865
2  some_string      16846846                      484     85.4865
3  some_string           NaN                      ...     85.4865
4  some_string      16846846                      484     85.4865
```

Comment: I have tried this regex ' \.* ' also but it is printing NaN after each letter of country in country column. eg: NaNANaNlNaNbNaNaNaNnNaNiNaNaNaN for Albania country

Comment: @AnkurSingh My bad, I used `*` instead of `+` which meant it inserted NaN even whithou the dot being present. I updated my answer accordingly.